# Best way to maintain Dependent softwares with versions in docker images?

Tags: docker

I am new to dockers, well we started working on docker file but I am stuck on how to maintain different versions of dependent software's of our web app.

suppose our web app uses crystal reports 1.X version, in runtime.

In future , if want to update version of crystal report to 1.2.X.

In these scenarios how a docker file and these dependent software's should be maintained(although version we can directly update in docker file)?

Should docker file be parametrised for the versions?

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Use your application language's native package dependency system (a Ruby `Gemfile`, Python `Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`, Node `package.json`, Scala `build.sbt`, ...).  In a non-Docker development environment, maintain these dependencies the same way you would without Docker.  When you go to translate this into a Dockerfile, copy these description files into the image and install them.

A near-universal Javascript Dockerfile, for example, would look like

```sh
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app

# Copy in and install dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install

# Copy in the rest of the application; build and set up to run it
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD yarn start
```

If a dependency changed, you'd use a command like `yarn up` to update the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files in your non-Docker development environment, and when you went to re-`docker build`, those updated files would update the dependency in the built image.

Comment: Hi David , thanks for your reply :) . Well at present we are using windows containers and there are certain exe's application is dependent on like crystal reports. which file (mentioned above )can be used for windows containers? or is there any other way to maintain for windows containers?